# приложение вылетает android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, исключения, logcat

Почему вылетает приложение при отладке на девайсе? Просто не запускается.

Вот логи при запуске приложения:

`01-06 00:28:39.970 8210-8210/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.go.fenom.home, PID: 8210
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.go.fenom.home/com.myapplication.Home}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapplication.Home" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapplication.Home" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.go.fenom.home-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1083)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832) 
01-06 00:28:39.977 8210-8210/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8210 SIG: 9`

И добавляю одно из активити.

```
package com.go.fenom.home;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.myapplication.R;


public class Gallery extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

DrawerLayout drawer;
NavigationView navigationView;
Toolbar toolbar=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //We dont need this.


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    //here is the main place where we need to work on.
    int id=item.getItemId();
    switch (id){

        case R.id.nav_home:
            Intent h= new Intent(Gallery.this, com.go.fenom.home.Home.class);
            startActivity(h);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_import:
            Intent i= new Intent(Gallery.this, com.go.fenom.home.Import.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            Intent g= new Intent(Gallery.this,Gallery.class);
            startActivity(g);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_slideshow:
            Intent s= new Intent(Gallery.this, com.go.fenom.home.Slideshow.class);
            startActivity(s);
        case R.id.nav_tools:
            Intent t= new Intent(Gallery.this, com.go.fenom.home.Tools.class);
            startActivity(t);
            break;

        // after this lets start copying the above.
        // FOLLOW MEEEEE>>>
        //copy this now.
    }



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Почему пакет `package com.go.fenom.home;` а импорт `import com.myapplication.R;`?

Влияет ли это на что то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если класс Home это активити то нужно прописать его в манифесте.приложение не может найти этот класс.

Comment: Внутри пакета com.myapplication должен быть класс Home.И если это активити то его ещё нужно прописать в манифесте.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!